# In Magento 1, Restrict a coupon code to a Not logged In customer Group?

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, guest-checkout

How to restrict coupon code for the guest user? I want to the guest user can apply code only one-time.on the other hand other customer groups can apply same coupon code more than one time.